# jQuery + select element by variable class (even if it has multplie classes)

Tags: jquery, class

This somewhat of an odd issue.
Summary:
I have some checkboxes  (they need to be be treated like radio buttons, ...dont ask)..lol

Meaning when one is selected, the others all need to be un-checked leaving the one that was just selected still checked.

There are several of these checkbox 'groups'.
Each 'group' shares the same className on a parent SPAN  (there is a parent span for each input checkbox to be clear.... the class in on the parent span itself)

However.. there is already a class name there by the time these spans/checkboxes are added and the new (additional) class dynamically added.

So any given GROUP (of spans) will all have the same class..

Such as:

```
ControlValue Class00
ControlValue Class01
ControlValue Class02
ControlValue Class03
ControlValue Class04
```

...etc..etc..

I'm trying to attempt the following:

When a checkbox is selected/checked..  I grab the parent span name, save it a variable to be used later,....grab a list of these elements with the same class name variable (ie: ControlValue Class00).. and then try to iterate through them unchecking the child() input checkbox.

However my selector is not working.. keeps coming up with 0 for length when I check it@

If I use a more generic selector and add in a hasClass()..it seems to work...

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var targetClass = $(this).parent().prop('class');
        //var targetParent = $(this).parent().hasClass(targetClass);

        console.log($('.'+targetClass).length); //0?  WTF?

        $('span .'+targetClass).each(function(i) { //doesnt work
        //$('div span').each( function(i) { //works
            //if ($(this).hasClass(targetClass) ) {
                //console.log("class found....");
                $(this).children("input[type='checkbox']:first").prop('checked', false);
            //}
        });         
        $(this).prop('checked', true); //leave self checked
    }   
});
```

I'm sure where I'm going wrong in my selector...?

JSFiddle to show example of markup

https://jsfiddle.net/vxpzs8sj/6/

update:

So both of these solutions work... I wasnt too keen on using a .hasClass() loop.. but I guess its not that bad of a solution..

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var targetClass = $(this).parent().prop('class'); 
        //or this works as well, more lines uses a .hasClass() loop 
        $('div span').each( function(i) { //works
            if ($(this).hasClass(targetClass) ) {
                $(this).children("input[type='checkbox']:first").prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
        $(this).prop('checked', true); //leave self checked
    }                                    
});
```

New approach (working solution as well)

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var targetClass = $(this).parent().prop('class'); 
        //this works (smaller code)
        $("span[class*='"+targetClass+"']").each(function(i) {
            $(this).children("input[type='checkbox']:first").prop('checked', false);
        });
        $(this).prop('checked', true); //leave self checked
    }                                    
});
```

Comment: Can you attach your HTML code here?

Comment: why the anonymous down vote?  bored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxpzs8sj/50/) (after a bit cleanup)

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var targetClass = $(this).parent().prop('class');

    $('.'+targetClass).each(function(i) {
     
     $(this).children("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
    });         
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
}   
});
```

```html
<!-- group 1 -->
<span class="span1 clas00">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" value="first_checkbox">
</span>
<span class="span1 clas00">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="first_checkbox">
</span>
<br>
<!-- group 2 -->
<span class="span2 clas01">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox3" value="first_checkbox">
</span>
<span class="span2 clas01">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox4" value="first_checkbox">
</span>
<br>
<!-- group 3 -->
<span class="span2 clas02">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox5" value="first_checkbox">
</span>
<span class="span2 clas02">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox6" value="first_checkbox">
</span>
<span id="lenght"></span>
<span id="class"></span>
<span id="spanObject"></span>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Say, when selecting the very first checkbox:

```
var targetClass = $(this).parent().prop('class');
// targetClass = 'span1 clas00'
```

so, `$('.'+targetClass)` = $('.span1 clas00'). **The problem is `clas00` is treated as HTML element instead of a class.** So, the `.each` loop is never executing actually.

The jQuery selector should be `$('.span1.clas00')` instead of `$('.span1 clas00')` (note, `.` between two class names)

---

### The working version:

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var targetClass = $(this).parent().prop('class');

    $('.'+targetClass.replace(" ", ".")).each(function(i) {
     
     $(this).children("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
    });         
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
}   
});
```

```html
<!-- group 1 -->
<span class="span1 clas00">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" value="first_checkbox">
</span>
<span class="span1 clas00">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="first_checkbox">
</span>
<br>
<!-- group 2 -->
<span class="span2 clas01">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox3" value="first_checkbox">
</span>
<span class="span2 clas01">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox4" value="first_checkbox">
</span>
<br>
<!-- group 3 -->
<span class="span2 clas02">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox5" value="first_checkbox">
</span>
<span class="span2 clas02">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cbox6" value="first_checkbox">
</span>
<span id="lenght"></span>
<span id="class"></span>
<span id="spanObject"></span>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

See **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxpzs8sj/51/)**

Comment: nice.. always good to know another solution, especially when it explains where the original failure was stemming from.  So to re-cap, prop('class') does in fact grab the first '.'  and the replace function is just to add in the second (missing one?)  I'll accept answer too!

Comment: not clear what you want to know exactly. here, `targetClass.replace(" ", ".")` is replacing all the `spaces with a `.` each. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Comment: You can fix that in many ways, here it is one of the ways. Just make sure `$('.className1.className2').each(...)` format.